# input box automatically changed to original value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I change the input box, it will automatically change to original value by itself. It seems the reason is `btnDisabled` has been changed, because if I remove the line of `this.btnDisabled = !this.btnDisabled;` the input box will no more be automatically changed. I want to know why `btnDisabled` will affect the input box's value?

```js
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        btnDisabled: false,
        total: 25,
    },
    created() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.btnDisabled = !this.btnDisabled;
        }, 500);
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-bind:value="total">

    <button v-bind:disabled="btnDisabled">test</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Vue is rerendering the "component" and the value is still technically 25. You can use `v-model` or `@input` to update the data or you can use `v-once` to prevent Vue from rerendering the input text box.

```js
const vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        btnDisabled: false,
        total: 25,
    },
    created() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.btnDisabled = !this.btnDisabled;
        }, 500);
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-bind:value="total" v-once>

    <button v-bind:disabled="btnDisabled">test</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer by `Steven B` which might solve your problem but I would like to add a little bit about the problem identifying the cause. The problem is in the `one-way-binding`, what I mean is that, when you are using the following:

```
<input type="text" v-bind:value="total">
```

You are introducing a new separate state in `DOM` by allowing the user typing in the input. So, when the user types into the input, the `data.total` property is not being updating, it's still `25` but the `DOM` input has new value. In that case, when `setInterval` fires and `data.btnDisabled` is updated, the Application's state is changed and then `VUE` just force the component to be re-render to keep the `data` and the `DOM` in sync. I would prefer `v-model` instead of `:value`.